# setState in react functional components is not being assigned property with assigned objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react functional component. I have a state called current property.

```
const [currentProperty, setCurrentProperty] = useState({})
```

I am trying to assign an object using the setCurrentProperty but it is not working the stat is staying as a black object. Here is the current code:

```
  function handleEditingMortagePaymentOpen(id){
    setCurrentlyEditingMortgagePayments(true)
    setSelectedPropertyById(id)
    for(let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
      if(properties[i]['id'] == id){
        console.log(properties[i])
        setCurrentProperty(properties[i])
        console.log(currentProperty)
      }
    }
  }
```

This is what the console.log is showing

```
{id: 3, picture: '../images/unnamed.jpeg', price: 464000, status: 'Active', beds: 3, …}
address: "Plan 2 Plan, Neo at Mission Foothils"
agent: "John Doe"
baths: 3
beds: 3
broker: "JD Realty"
days_listed: 29
hoa: 12
home_insurance: 239
id: 3
living_space: 3964
mls: "OC3628342"
picture: "../images/unnamed.jpeg"
price: 464000
property_tax: 68
rent: 2200
sqft: 1939
status: "Active"
[[Prototype]]: Object
{}
```

Comment: you are expecting the console.log to reflect the change, but this is not how react state updates work. I would recommend you read up on how state updates are triggered in react

Comment: Using a loop to continually set state isn't a great idea.

Comment: True, although this code is equivalent to a `arr.find(item); setCurrentProperty(item)` since its only matching by an id which I'd assume is a unique identifier. The issue is the set state behavior being async vs sync. Its a common question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue mentioned in
[useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

React setState or useState function will not instantly change your variable, it is an asynchronous process that will only set your value on its next render,

```
    console.log(properties[i])
    setCurrentProperty(properties[i])
    console.log(currentProperty)
```

This code show different logs as current property is not yet updated with the new one,
To check the change of a state variable you can check it outside you function (before the return of component) or in a `useEffect`

```
 useEffect(()=> {
    conole.log(currentProperty) // this will console latest value on your every `currentProperty` update
 },[currentProperty])
```

or you can simply console it before you return the HTML, or inside HTML,
value will automatically updates on its next render